# i want to integrating R with PHP (if i use any R packages in R code it doesn't work!)

Tags: php, r

i want to integration R with PHP. so i used exec function in PHP or COM class.
i works well if i don't use any package function in R code.

but any package function in R code, it doesn't work.
maybe some error are there. but i don't know how to check.

please check my code.

PHPCODE

```
<?
$e = exec('Rscript C:\Users\KOO\Documents\R\FoodTrain.R', $result);
print_r($result);
$str = $result[0];
$str1 = $result[1];
?>
```

Rcode

```
require(e1071)
require(RODBC)
require(sqldf)

a<-array(data=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1),dim=c(4,2))
b<-factor(c(1,-1,-1,1))
a
b


dbConn <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0; Server=localhost; Database=test; Uid=test; Pwd=test")
```

returning

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    1    0
[4,]    1    1
[1] 1  -1 -1 1 
Levels: -1 1
```

BUT if R CODE is

```
require(e1071)
require(RODBC)
require(sqldf)

dbConn <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0; Server=localhost; Database=test; Uid=test; Pwd=test")

a<-array(data=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1),dim=c(4,2))
b<-factor(c(1,-1,-1,1))
a
b
```

it returns

```
Array ( )
```

i am running :

- windows7
- MS-SQL
- APACHE, PHP 5.3.3
- R 3.1

i can't found solution. please help me!

Comment: Blind sh!t?! HAHA! I guess you meant blind **shot**.

Comment: i think 'Require' is not working. if i t<-require(e1071) t is FALSE. what should i do ? T.T